# can anybody help me to find the number of times the zero will occur from 1-1000

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, count

Example to count number of 0 from 1 - 100 
the output should be `count = 11`

I tried this as well as tried using mod function but couldn't get the output.

```
DECLARE 
    VNUM NUMBER := &NUMBER; 
    VCOUNT NUMBER := 0; 
BEGIN 
    FOR I IN 1..VNUM LOOP 
        IF SUBSTR(I,-I, 1) = 0 THEN 
            VCOUNT := VCOUNT + 1; 
        END IF; 
    END LOOP; 

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VCOUNT); 
END; 
/
```

Comment: Have you issued `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` before running this to enable DBMS_OUTPUT terminal output?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use SQL:

```
select sum(regexp_count(val, '0')) 
  from (select level as val from dual connect by level <= 1000)
```

Which returns for 11 for 1-100, 192 for 1-1000.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (though similar) approach is to use `MOD` to 'chop' the leading digits off and then check the remainder

I've amended it to count the 0 in each number instead. To be honest, not dissimilar to 'Ponder Stibbons' solution but this one does not use reg exps.

```
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

    DECLARE 
        VNUM NUMBER := &NUMBER; 
        COUNT_THIS NUMBER := &DIGIT;
        VCOUNT NUMBER := 0; 
        Zs NUMBER := 0;
    BEGIN 
        FOR I IN 1..VNUM LOOP 
           -- Count 0s - remove non-0 digits and get length of the remainder
           Zs := LENGTH(REPLACE(translate(to_char(i), '987654321', 'zzzzzzzzz' ), 'z', ''));
           VCOUNT := VCOUNT + NVL(Zs, 0 );
--            IF MOD(i,10) = COUNT_THIS THEN 
--                VCOUNT := VCOUNT + 1; 
--            END IF; 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( I || ' has ' || Zs || ' zeroes '); 
        END LOOP; 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of ' || COUNT_THIS || ' in range = ' || VCOUNT); 
    END; 
    /
```

Comment: THIS WILL NOT INCLUDE THE SECOND ZERO OF 100

Comment: OK. Before I make a suggestion, each 0 within trailing sequence of  0's within a range of numbers should be counted, right? So, 101, 1001 are not counted, but 100 is counted as 2, and 11000 is counted as 3? Right?

Comment: 1000 as 3 and 1001 as 2